# Android SQLite3 Anomaly with DISTINCT?

Tags: distinct, android-sqlite

This query does not return what I would expect. Why?

The table:

```
create table t
(
    comment varchar(10),
    id int
);
```

The data:

```
insert into t values ('C1', 1);
insert into t values ('C2', 2);
insert into t values ('C3', 3);
insert into t values ('C4', 4);
insert into t values ('C5', 5);
insert into t values ('C6', 6);
insert into t values ('C7', 7);
insert into t values ('C8', 8);
insert into t values ('C9', 9);
insert into t values ('C1', 10);
```

The query:

```
select distinct comment from t order by id desc limit 8;
```

The result:

```
C9
C8
C7
C6
C5
C4
C3
C2
```

When I leave DISTINCT out, I get the last row, but I want to suppress duplicates.
My workaround returns the correct result set:

```
select comment from t group by comment order by max(id) desc limit 8;
```

But I am curious if my query is not valid (T-SQL for example does not allow both a DISTINCT and ORDER BY in one query unless the ordered column is in the select list) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, just guess, that C1 is out of selection cuz it has a dupe and also I guess that it SQL-selects this dupe with id 10 instead of 1. Thats why you got ids from 2 to 9 (totally 8 like you'd asked from SQL by limit 8). Please check if my theory is true. I guess its work flow like record with id 1, ok no dupes, next, id2, no dupes, ok..., id 10 - is dupe of id 1, removing record with id 1, adding record with id 10...

Comment: Not really an answer, but I'll accept it anyway as the only answer.